# Jitsi as a VoIP SIP softphone with asterisk - calls don't work

Tags: linux, voip, asterisk, sip, jitsi

I have an asterisk server and I am trying to use Jitsi Desktop on Debian 11 as a SIP softphone (like [Jami](https://jami.net/) and [Linphone](https://www.linphone.org/)) to connect to it and make calls.

Jitsi can register and connect to the asterisk server without any problems:
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFwSe.jpg)

Jitsi configs that I used when adding the SIP account:
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqdn3.jpg)
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBo7F.jpg)

However when I try to call *43 to make an echo test call, jitsi calls itself and it does not make any calls to the asterisk server.

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLCH9.jpg)

Is there any specific configuration needed to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

By following the configuration found [here](https://superuser.com/q/942280/728050), I was able to use Jitsi as a VoIP SIP Softphone by setting the same setting as the Registrar/Port for Proxy/Server port fields.

[SIP settings required for Jitsi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOxSG.png)

Registrar: Voip Server
Port: VoipSipPort

uncheck "Configure proxy automatically" and enter the same settings for Proxy server and port:

Proxy: Voip Server
Port: VoipSipPort
Preferred Transport: (Choose the requried transport TCP/UDP/TLS)